# What does "PRIVATE" in "PRIVATE int func_name()" in c?

Tags: c

I have a following C function,

```
PRIVATE int func_name()
{
   return 0;
}
```

What does "PRIVATE" mean here?

Comment: Where did you found the code?

Comment: It means whatever it was `#define`d to mean ... probably `static`.

Comment: Voting to close this as "cannot get reproduced". Please add more details and show the definition of `PRIVATE`. As it currently stands, nobody can answer the question, they can just do guessing. (One of many reasons why it is royally stupid to re-define the C language into your own secret macro language.)

Answer (score 8):

In "normal" C `PRIVATE` has no meaning.

It is probably a `#define` to `static` (or perhaps nothing). I'd suggest trying to grab the output of the pre-processor to see what it looks like. In gcc it's `-E` to stop after the pre-processor stage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes someone might have #defined `PRIVATE` as static. search for #define of private in your code. They should have defined something like this `#define PRIVATE static`

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Just to restrict the scope, they defined it as "static".